# Fields from different content types in a single page

Tags: users, nodes

Using field permissions i have set 10 fields from various content types (articles, page, etc) to private.

While the rest of the fields is filled by the user, the publisher needs verify and fill those 10 fields to publish the content.

Is it possible to get all these fields in a single page so the publisher don't have to go to the individual content types to fill those fields.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drupal Answers. I am not clear why you put those fields on different content types. Would not creating a content type with all the needed fields be easier?

Comment: I have set some fields from each content type(there are like 3 content types) for the publisher to enter before publishing the content. so he has to visit every content type for entering the values and set it to published. I was looking for a way to show all the fields the publisher has to enter in a single page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't restructure your publishing flow as kiamlaluno said (preferred method!), then another option would be to write a custom module to programmatically retrieve the info from each field and display them for the publisher's review in a form, then store the publisher's revisions in each field. See these pages for more info, [Drupal API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_value/7) and another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074485/drupal-7-how-to-render-custom-field)

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be to rethink your publishing workflow.

Having that said, I would try to create a view which takes content from all content types. Instead of showing the content, show the appropriate fields and create a filter so only unpublished content is shown...

Comment: A view doesn't allow to edit fields; it just allows to show a list of nodes. I agree with rethinking the publishing workflow, though.

Comment: isn't it logical for a role to be able to fill in all their assigned fields from different content types with ease... guaranteed only they have those field permissions. There should be something may be am using the wrong words. :( and  thanks for your replies :)